# Double Induction on Ramsey's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, ramsey-theory

I am studying Ramsey Theorem from Introduction to Graph Theory by Douglas West, 2nd edition. I could not get some part of its proof. Here is the theorem,

> 8.3.7. Theorem. (Ramsey [1930]) Given positive integers $r$ and $p_1, ..., p_k$, there exists an integer $N$ such that every $k$-coloring of
>   $\binom{[N]}{r}$ yields an $i$-homogeneous set of size $p_i$ for some
>   $i$.

Double induction is used in the proof, on $r$ and $\sum p_i$. I could not understand the part below in the proof.

> Basis step: Some quota $p_i$ is less than $r$. In this case, a set of $p_i$ objects contains no $r$-sets, so vacuously its $r$-sets all have color $i$. Hence $R(p_1, ..., p_k; r) = min\{p_1, . . . , p_k\}$ when $min\{p_1, ... , p_k\} < r$.

How $p_i$ being less than $r$ causes this situation ? I didn't understand why $r$ and $p_i$ are related like above. We're choosing $r$-element subsets of $[N]$, so there will be $\frac{N!}{r!(N-r)!}$ subsets to be partitioned into $k$ classes.

Comment: I think since $p_i$ is less than $r$, so we cannot choose an r-set wholly from those $p_i$ elements which are independent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that there is an $i$ such that $p_i<r$, and let $c$ be a $k$-coloring of $\binom{[N]}r$. Let $S\subseteq[N]$ be any set of $p_i$ objects. Then $S$ has no $r$-subsets, so it is vacuously true that every $r$-subset of $S$ has color $i$. If that point is where you’re having trouble, ask yourself what would be needed to show that $S$ was **not** $i$-homogeneous: you’d have to fine two $r$-subsets of $S$ that were colored differently. But you can’t find even **one** $r$-subset of $S$, so you certainly can’t find two with different colors!

Thus, in this case $R(p_1,\ldots,p_k;r)\le p_i$. I write ‘$\le$’ because there might be an even smaller $p_j$, in which case the same argument would apply to show that $R(p_1,\ldots,p_k;r)\le p_j$. Thus, we might as well simply pick the smallest quota and observe that

$$R(p_1,\ldots,p_k;r)=\min\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$$

if $\min\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}<r$.

Comment: How is "Then $S$ has no $r$-subsets" part concluded ?

Comment: @Melike For example, how many subsets of size $10$ does the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ have?

Comment: @MishaLavrov None but in your example $[N]=5$ and $r=10$. In the theorem, $p_i$ is less than $r$, not $N$. I still could not get it.

Comment: @Melike: $S$ has $p_i$ elements, and $p_i$ is smaller than $r$. $S$ isn't big enough to have even **one** $r$-element subset. It's like Misha's example: a set with only $5$ members doesn't have any subsets of size $10$.

Comment: @Melike: No, in Misha's example $S$ is $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: The claim is that if $p_i < r$, then we can set $N = p_i$, take $S = [N]$, and then $S$ will be a subset of $[N]$ of size $p_i$ with no $r$-subsets. This works fine if $N = p_i = 5$ and $r=10$.

Comment: (remember: when the theorem says "there exists $N$", then we get to pick what $N$ is in the proof)